# Making a threadsafe queue in Haskell using MVar (maybe?)

Tags: multithreading, haskell, thread-safety, locking

In Haskell, I want to create a threadsafe queue, with two operations:

1. Remove ALL elements from the queue.
2. Add 1 element to the queue.

My first thought was to use the type `MVar (NonEmpty a)`

The operations will be implemented as follows:

1. Just use `takeMVar`. This will leave the `MVar` empty. Reverse the returned list because as noted below, the elements are stored in reverse order.
2. IF the `MVar` is empty, insert the singleton list with the element to insert. But if the `MVar` has data in it, append that element to the list.

The problem is that, I can't see in the documentation for `MVar` how to do point 2 atomically. I can `putMVar`, or I can `modifyMVar`, but (I presume) both of these functions could potentially block (if the `MVar` is full or empty respectively), but inserting into the queue should never block (only reading from it should).

I presume there's a way around this issue? Is `MVar` just the wrong primitive or can I combine them in some different way?

Comment: Maybe [stm](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm) works better for you.

Comment: Also, up to documentation,`modifyMVar` is [atomic](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent-MVar.html) if all other threads do `takeMVar` before `putMVar`. So _I think_, If you have these operations and _only_ these ones, your queue is updated atomically.  You can also take a look to the `Control.Concurrent.Chan` module.

Comment: Perhaps `MVar (NonEmpty a)` is the wrong representation. It represents the condition "empty list (all elements removed)" and "variable taken by another thread" in the same way. Maybe I'd use `MVar [a]` instead. It's unclear if you want operation 1 to wait until the queue is nonempty, in which case it looks more complicated to achieve with `MVar`s. (stm looks easier to use for this).

Comment: Yes, I want operation 1 to block if the queue is empty. I also want all operations to always succeed, even if they temporarily block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy way to implement concurrent data structures is [STM](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm), because it lets you make arbitrary sequences of operations atomic. It's also easy to block with `retry`: `pop` is suspended and will re-run from the start only when one of the variables it read previously has been written to.

```
import Control.Concurrent.STM

newtype Queue a = Queue (TVar [a])

push :: a -> Queue a -> IO ()
push x (Queue q) = atomically $ do
  xs <- readTVar q
  writeTVar q (x : xs)

pop :: Queue a -> IO [a]
pop (Queue q) = atomically $ do
  xs <- readTVar q
  case xs of
    [] -> retry
    _ -> do
      writeTVar q []
      return (reverse xs)
```